# ": not found" and syntax error in my first ever shell script

Tags: shell-script

The shell script, I am trying to create, should be run by crontab regularly, and it should call a perl script which saves email attachments to a predefined directory.

Here's what I came up with:

```
backup_day=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

backup_dir=/private-backup/email_attachment_cleaner/korrespondenztest/$backup_day

if [ ! -d $backup_dir ]
then
    mkdir -p $backup_dir
fi

if [ ! -d $backup_dir ]
then
    echo "Error"
    exit 1
fi

output_file=/root/email_attachment_cleaner/history.txt

perl /root/email_attachment_cleaner/email_attachment_cleaner.pl -O $backup_dir -lots-of-further-parameters >> $output_file
```

When I save this script in `/root/email_attachment_cleaner/` and run it with `sudo sh /root/email_attachment_cleaner/email_attachment_cleaner.sh`, I get the following output:

```
: not found_attachment_cleaner/email_attachment_cleaner.sh: 2: /root/email_attachment_cleaner/email_attachment_cleaner.sh:
: not found_attachment_cleaner/email_attachment_cleaner.sh: 4: /root/email_attachment_cleaner/email_attachment_cleaner.sh:
/root/email_attachment_cleaner/email_attachment_cleaner.sh: 19: /root/email_attachment_cleaner/email_attachment_cleaner.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
```

It appears to me that the given line numbers are probably "wrong" and should be 1, 3 and 18 instead. However, this output does not help me at all.
What's going on here?

I needed quite some time to figure out that empty lines in the script should contain at least a space. Is that right?

Comment: it gets worse...

Comment: which means exactly?

Comment: Nothing meaningful - I thought your question was titled funny.

Comment: If you do `sudo sh /root/email_attachment_cleaner/email_attachment_cleaner.sh 2>&1 | cat -v` do you see any `^M` characters?

Comment: "I needed quite some time to figure out that empty lines in the script should contain at least a space. Is that right?" No, not at all. The problem, as Mark notes, is that when you transferred the file from Windows, you kept all the `^M` (carriage-returns) in the file. Get rid of those using `sed -i 's/\r$//' /root/email_attachment_cleaner/email_attachment_cleaner.sh`. 

Otherwise, there are no serious problems with the script. Christopher's advice is sound, but strictly speaking, not needed.

Comment: Otheus is correct by pointing out Windows' CR as the original problem. I am sorry that I did not figure this out, but with the output's error messages, I was obviously and unfortunately not able to look for the correct keywords. How should I proceed with this duplicate question? Edit? Delete?